# Background tint overlay not extending on scroll

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to create a tint on my background of a modal but I can't get it to extend to the full height of the content if the content doesn't fit on the page and needs to scroll. The tint only goes to the height of the modal and doesn't scroll.

Here is the code for the modal:

```
<div class="reveal recipeModal" id="<?php echo $slug; ?>"  style="background:url(<?php the_field('image'); ?>) center center;background-size: cover;" data-reveal data-animation-in="fade-in" data-animation-out="fade-out">

    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-x recipeDetails">
            <img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" class="printableImage" />
            <div class="cell small-12 doubleUnderline"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></div>
                <h6 class="cell small-9 time">Start to Finish: <?php the_field('preparation_time'); ?></h6>
                <h6 class="cell small-3 text-right servings">Servings: <?php the_field('servings'); ?></h6>
                <div class="recipeInstructions">
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><button class="button large printButton darkButton" style="margin:0;" onclick="window.print();return false;">Print Recipe</button></a>
            </div>   

        </div>   

        <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    <div class="tint"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the sass code used on it:

```
.recipeModal{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50% !important;
    left: 50%;
    width: 75%;
    height:85%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    .tint{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position: fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        padding:1em;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        z-index:10000;
    }
    .close-button:hover{
        color:$orange;
    }
    h4{
        color:white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border-bottom:10px solid white;
        font-weight: 900;
        font-size: 35px;
    }
    .recipeDetails{
        h6{
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color:white;
            font-weight: 500;
            margin-top: 15px;
        } 
        .recipeInstructions{
            strong{
                font-weight: 700;
                text-decoration: underline;
                font-size:25px;
            }
            color:white;
            font-size:20px;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000000;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the problem I am trying to solve:
[image]

As you can see in the pic the tint gets cutoff where the scroll begins (I couldn't screenshot the whole page because it would make the image too big to upload)

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or codepen link with the problem? I'm not sure that elements with position: fixed should be inside something else since position fixed works relative to window element (height: 100% is the height of the window, not the document), maye you can try with position: absolute for .tint